# Is executePendingTransactions() always necessary?

Tags: android, android-fragments

This is more of a theoretical question.

I have a situation where my app crashes on a fragment swap with an `executePendingTransactions()` call and works fine without it.

My question is what could go wrong in general if i don't call `executePendingTransactions()`?

As i understand, without this method a `Fragment` swap may not happen immediately, although i have never experienced this.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's not required unless you are executing something that depends on the transaction. From the [API documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#executePendingTransactions%28%29),

> After a `FragmentTransaction` is committed with
>   `FragmentTransaction.commit()`, it is scheduled to be executed
>   asynchronously on the process's main thread. If you want to
>   immediately executing any such pending operations, you can call this
>   function (only from the main thread) to do so. Note that all callbacks
>   and other related behavior will be done from within this call, so be
>   careful about where this is called from.

Comment: Can you give some real time use case on this statement - "It's not required unless you are executing something that depends on the transaction"